# Pulling random switch cases

Tags: php, switch-statement

I have a switch function I want to be able to randomly pull cases from:

```
<?php
    function peopleGet($name) {
        switch ($name) { 

            case 'gloria': 
            echo 'gloria';
            break;

            case 'benjamin': 
            echo 'benjamin';
            break;

            case 'callum': 
            echo 'callum';
            break;
        }
    }
?>
```

I still need to be able to pull specific variables:

```
<?php peopleGet('gloria'); ?>
```

However, is it possible to use the same function to be able to pull random (no-repeating) cases?

Comment: No idea what you are asking. What exactly *is* a case that you want to "pull out"? And that last code block is... baffling.

Comment: as far as I know, case labels always need to be constant values.

Comment: @DanielvanDommele: Not in PHP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is **no** (And really you shouldn't) because the switch case statement is a **control structure** not a data structure, you would be better of having an array of values instead, plus instead of retuning a single value you can return multiple values

Something like:

```
<?php 
function peopleGet($name=null){
    $people = array('gloria'=>array('name'=>'Gloria',
                                    'age'=>'29',
                                    'location'=>'usa'),
                  'benjamin'=>array('name'=>'Benjamin',
                                    'age'=>'39',
                                    'location'=>'uk'),
                    'callum'=>array('name'=>'Callum',
                                    'age'=>'19',
                                    'location'=>'uk'));

    if($name==null){
        $keys = array_keys($people);
        shuffle($keys);
        return $people[$keys[mt_rand(0,count($people)-1)]];
    }else{
        return $names[$name];
    }                         
}
print_r(peopleGet());//random
print_r(peopleGet('gloria'));//gloria's array
?>
```

Comment: This is spot on. I will switch the data to arrays in this this case. Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: I just changed it to add the random return if no value is passed to the function

Comment: @Dyin i like tobe different na actually using just array_rand($people) would return just the key, i wanted the whole array as its multidimensional ;p

Comment: The solution for this is: `$peopleArray[array_rand($peopleArray)]` ;)

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you want to achieve?

```
$peopleArray=Array('gloria'   => 'gloria',
                   'benjamin' => 'benjamin',
                   'callum'   => 'callum');
```

Get a distinct value with: `$myPerson=$peopleArray['gloria'];`

Get a random value with: `$myPerson=$peopleArray[array_rand($peopleArray)];`

Note: [array_rand manual](http://hu2.php.net/manual/en/function.array-rand.php) — Pick one or more random entries out of an array

Answer (score 0):

Are you referring to the `default:` clause that catches cases that haven't beeen defined?

```
switch ($name) { 
    // Gloria
    case 'gloria': 
    echo 'gloria';
    break;

    // Benjamin
    case 'benjamin': 
    echo 'benjamin';
    break;

    // Callum
    case 'callum': 
    echo 'callum';
    break;

    default:
    echo $name; // or whatever that needs to happen if it is an undefined case
    break;
}
```

Comment: No, although I didn't know about the default in the switch. I need to be able for the switch to output a random case.